# Error in my function that contains pointers?

Tags: c++

```
  void multiplyByRefPointer(Fraction *f1,Fraction *f2,Fraction *f3)
  {
        *f3.num = f1.num*f2.num;
        *f3.den = f1.den*f2.den;

    cout << "Result :" << &f3.num << "/" << &f3.den;
  }
```

The error I've been getting says "request for member 'num' and 'den' for f1,f2, and f3."

How would I go about multiplying this?

Comment: Change `.` to `->` like `f1->num`.

Comment: Please also extract a [mcve] from your code before asking here. This issue has really nothing to do with the code being in a function, so that part would have been clarified by that.

Answer (score 0):

f1,f2,f3 are pointers if you want to access to a member  use *f.member or f->member

```
void multiplyByRefPointer(Fraction *f1,Fraction *f2,Fraction *f3)
{
   f3->num = f1->num * f2->num;
   f3->den = f1->den * f2->den;

   cout << "Result :" << f3->num << "/" << f3->den;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@camelCaseuser. Your problem is obvious. You're miss-using the pointer to **struct**.
If you declare:

```
struct frac {
    int num;
    int den;
};
```

then in a regular usage, you can access **members of struct frac** by doing for example:

```
int n = frac.num;
int d = frac.den;
```

However to access the members of *pointer to struct frac* i.e **struct frac *f**, you must
do:

```
int n = *(f).num;
int d = *(f).den;
```

or simply, user *->* operator such that:

```
int n = f->num;
int d = f->den;
```

hence, your function could read:

```
void multiplyByRefPointer(Fraction *f1,Fraction *f2,Fraction *f3)
{
    f3->num = f1->num * f2->num;
    f3->den = f1->den * f2->den;

    cout << "Result :" << f3->num << "/" << f3->den;
}
```

Comment: As an added note, prefer passing the parameters as references rather than pointers here. You have to go out of your way to accidentally pass in a NULL or other invalid address with a reference.